# Why does the IPv6 header not include a checksum?

Tags: ip, network, ipv6, protocol-theory, checksum

It is stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) that

> an IPv6 header does not include a checksum.

What are the reasons that were behind this decision?

Comment: To make router hardware cheaper.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

One of the ideas around IPv6 was to speed up packet forwarding. To that end, several decisions were made. For example, the IPv6 header was greatly simplified and is a fixed length, unlike the variable length IPv4 header. Also, you cannot fragment IPv6 packets along the path, the way you can for IPv4, because packet fragmentation is resource intensive.

Not having a checksum in the IPv6 header means that an IPv6 router does not need to recalculate the checksum to see if the packet header is corrupt, and recalculate the checksum after decrementing the hop count. That saves processing time and speeds up the packet forwarding. The logic is that the layer-2 and layer-4 protocols each already have a checksum. The layer-2 checksum covers the entire IPv6 packet, and the layer-4 checksum covers the transport datagram.

Where UDP has an optional checksum for IPv4, it is required for IPv6.

Comment: And even in IPv4, the UDP checksum is strongly recommended. RFC 1122 says it has to default to enabled, and "The advisability of ever
                 turning off UDP checksumming is very controversial." It's probably considered a design mistake that the original spec made it optional.

Comment: That is all true, but when you look at the networking tag on [so], most of the programmers there that do things like raw sockets simply set it to `0` (disabled) and ignore any incoming CRCs. It appears to be too difficult for them to calculate the CRC.

Comment: If they're just toy applications, I guess they can get away with it.

Comment: Based on what I have seen on [so], the guys programming network applications really do not understand networking, and that really scares me. No wonder we have so many vulnerabilities in network applications. It's OK if they are just learning, but some of them have some real stuff in production, and I would not run any of it, except I do not know the names.

Comment: Most questions on SO are from beginners, so it's hard to extrapolate. But I agree that programming seems to be an area where many people feel comfortable working without much formal education. Would anyone hire an architect who learned from Internet tutorials?

Comment: How is an IPv6 header not a layer 2 thing?

Comment: Layer-2 protocols are link-layer protocols that only talk on the same LAN (ethernet, Wi-Fi, token ring, FDDI, PPP, HDLC, frame relay, ATM, etc.). IP (both IPv4 and IPv6) is _Internet_ Protocol, meaning between networks. Layer-2 operates on the same network, layer-3 operates between networks. IP would be unnecessary if we did not need to communicate between networks. In the old days, there were single LAN protocols that have now faded away because we live in a layer-3 world.

Comment: @RonMaupin Amen to that. I'm a sysadmin (with a programming background) and I need to support a large development department working on networked devices. Most programmers don't have a clue and are outright dangerous. Most can't even configure the network settings of their own computer properly. You wouldn't believe how many times I have said "No, the DHCP server isn't broken. Don't set your laptop to static IP."

Comment: @RonMaupin Why  Ipv6 header is fixed, it has next header field which makes Ipv6 header would be variable?

Comment: The IPv6 header is a fixed size of 40 octets, unlike the IPv4 header that can be anywhere from 20 to 60 octets. It takes extra code and time to determine the IPv4 packet header size. The IPv6 extension headers are only for the destination. The intermediate devices (routers), do not deal with the IPv6 extension headers (except for Option 0, but only if explicitly configured to examine that option if present). The code for IPv6 routing is faster than for IPv4 because it can just deal with a fixed-size header.

Comment: @AlokMaity, "_Extension headers (except for the Hop-by-Hop Options header) are not processed, inserted, or deleted by any node along a packet's delivery path, until the packet reaches the node (or each of the set of nodes, in the case of multicast) identified in the Destination Address field of the IPv6 header._" Also, "_NOTE: While [RFC2460] required that all nodes must examine and process the Hop-by-Hop Options header, it is now expected that nodes along a packet's delivery path only examine and process the Hop-by-Hop Options header if explicitly configured to do so._"

Answer (score 27):

Because it's redundant.

All the common link-layer protocols, like Ethernet or WiFi, have their own error checking and error correction mechanisms, so physical transmission errors are already unlikely.

What's left are logic errors in the packet itself. But almost all transport protocols based on IPv6, like TCP or UDP, also have error checking to catch logical errors. And these checksums often cover parts of the IP header as well, even though those aren't technically part of the transport layer segment (like source and destination address).

So what's the worst that could happen if an IPv6 router tries to route a corrupted packet? The packet will either not get routed at all, because the header contains invalid values or the destination address doesn't exist, or the address is a valid one (which might or might not be the intended one), so it will arrive at a destination, which will then discard it because the transport layer checksum doesn't add up. A bit of bandwidth got wasted, and that's it. And that is a scenario which doesn't really happen all that often. So it's simply not worth the additional CPU load you need on IPv6 switches to calculate the checksum for every single packet they route.

Comment: Shifting responsibility up a layer, more or less.

Comment: @Andrew: yeah, but the checksum calculation in UDP, TCP and DCCP over IPv4 already included the source and destination addresses. ICMP had a separate checksum algorithm, but it was only a small step to change this algorithm in ICMPv6 and drop the now effectively superfluous IP header checksum. The only IP-based layer 4 protocol I know that has a checksum which doesn't cover the src/dest addresses is SCTP.

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere before, from someone who knew the thought process that went into this decision: IPv4 headers have a checksum, whereas IPv6 headers don't, because by the time it came to designing IPv6, networking technology in general had improved so much (much fewer errors, etc., and besides, even the rare errors that did occur, could be caught by checksums at other layes) so that the benefits of including a checksum in the IPv6 header were minimal.

Each field that would be added to the IPv6 header would add additional overhead to a header that was already larger than the IPv4 header, given that IPv6 addresses are longer than IPv4 addresses. For something that was of minimal benefit, it was considered not necessary.

Comment: Actually, prior to 1995, when IPv6 was published, IPv6 was being developed, and analog modem dial-up was the rule. WAN technology was still very primitive and error-prone. It may have been that the IPv6 designers could anticipate that IPv6 would be delayed so long that network technology would get better, but I doubt it because they wanted it to be adopted right away since the Internet was going commercial in 1995.

Comment: PPP already handled checksumming, only SLIP would've been an issue.